# How to create dynamic payload for SOAP in karate

Tags: karate

I am using a variable to read XML file and then assign that in to another variable called payload. Passing that XML as CDATA in the payload; My payload structure will not change. I have to make three to five consecutive SOAP calls with different XML files ie, different CDATA. Right now I am repeating this code to make three to five consecutive SOAP calls, is there any way to avoid repeating the same code or Can you suggest me a better way to write.

```
* def temp = read('abc.xml')

* xmlstring data = temp

* def payload = 
"""
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UFT-8"?>
<soapenv:Envalope xmlns:...........>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <saopenv: Body>
    <con:processRequest>
      <xmlMessage><!CDATA[#(data)]]></xmlMessage>
       ..............
       .........
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv: Envalop>

"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your questions will be answered if you can go through this large example: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature).

But here is one example, refer this section in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests

```
* xmlstring data = read(filename)
* def payload = 
"""
<root><value>#(data)</value></root>
"""

Examples:
| filename |
| abc.xml  |
| def.xml  |
```